Geometry question to find area of triangle inside quadrilateral
I am having trouble with the following geometry question.


We are given that $BC=CD$, $\angle CBA = 90^\circ$, Area of $\square ABCD = 54$, Area of $\triangle ABD = 17$.
We are asked to calculate the area of $\triangle ACD$.

I have been playing around with it for a while and have come up with several relationships between angles, but do not seem to be getting anywhere.
I have,
$\angle BCD = 2\angle ABD$
$\frac{AB}{BC}\tan(\angle ABD)=\frac{17}{37}$
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Who says ADC is not a right angle?

Welcome to Math.SE! ... "I [...] have come up with several relationships between angles" Please include such relations in the body of the question. After all, it may be easy for others to point out how to proceed using them (or note an error in them). Plus, showing your work can help others avoid wasting time duplicating your effort. ... Good luck!

Thanks, blue. I've added what I have so far to the question.

Since the problem seems under-defined, let's do some wishful thinking of unique cases, and check to see if area of $ \triangle ACD$ is the same. If yes, that will help motivate towards an answer. If no, then this question is ill-posed.
Let's consider the case where $ \angle BCD = 90^\circ$.
Then $AB \parallel CD$, and Area of $\triangle ACD = $ Area of $\triangle BCD = 54 - 17 = 37$.
Note that such a setup satisfying the conditions can indeed be achieved.
Let's consider the case where $D$ is the reflection of $B$ in $CA$.
Then Area of $\triangle ACD = \frac{1}{2} \times $ Area of $ABCD = 27$.
Note that such a setup satisfying the conditions can indeed be achieved.
Hence, the problem does not have a unique answer.
I can believe (but am not doing the work to justify) that we could make $ACD$ have an area of any value between 27 and 37. It's also likely possible to have an area outside of this range.
In conclusion, the problem is too under-defined, which makes it somewhat meaningless.

Thank you for your time and effort. I can see now that the question is unsolvable. I have built the diagram in Desmos here. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s2jboz9dy7 . It can be seen that there are infinitely many solutions as the areas in the question are satisfied for all values of k. I have to conclude that a piece of information is missing. The answer is supposedly 20 so I don't know what additional constraint must have been given.
